# Read stdin non-blocking

Tags: vala

I'm writing a Vala program which is spawned as a child_process using stdout & stdin for message transfer with parent. In an async method I call read_stdin(sb) to check for incoming messages. I tried various stdin methods like gets and getc, but they all appear to block on '\n' newline. I need to read all chars available and return immediately (non-blocking).

```
    const int STDIN_BUF_SIZE=1024;
    char[] stdin_buffer;
    bool read_stdin (StringBuilder sb) {
        int iPos=0;
        int c;
        int buf_size=STDIN_BUF_SIZE-1;
        // Char by char:
        while (true) {
            c = stdin.getc ();
            if(c ==  GLib.FileStream.EOF) break;
            stdin_buffer[iPos]=(char)c;
            iPos++;
            if ((char)c=='\n'||iPos==buf_size){
                break;
                }
            }
        if(iPos>0){
            stdin_buffer[iPos]=0;
            sb.append((string)stdin_buffer);
            return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Can stdin be used for non-blocking IO or do I need to create something like...

```
DataInputStream stdin_reader = new DataInputStream(stdin);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the term "non-blocking", but I don't think that means what you think it means. It would be pretty easy to simply open `/dev/stdin` with `O_NONBLOCK` if non-blocking I/O was what you really wanted. In that case, `getc` would instantly return `EOF` until there is data available.

AFAICT, what you want is actually for the `getc` call to block until new data is available, then immediately return. Technically, that's what is happening. The wrinkle is that terminal applications typically buffer data until a newline, which explains why you can edit data and not have any edits appear to your application; go ahead, try typing "AB" into your program, and all you'll see will be "B\n".

Basically, you need to use a [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29).  Vala includes a curses.vapi, so you should just need to link to the relevant library (probably ncurses) and add `--pkg curses` to your `valac` invocation and you'll be good to go. IIRC the relevant function is `getch`, but I haven't done any curses programming in a *long* time.

Comment: Always great effort in respectful detailed explanations including alternatives. It's educational and greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If you want to go a little more low level than curses, you should read about the difference between raw and cooked mode or in general terminal modes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode

Comment: Oh and here is a tutorial on how to build a text editor in C which might also be of interest: https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/